# triggering socket.io-client to issue a disconnect on reboot

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have a server and client in node.js. The client is using socket.io-client and the server is using socket.io. I have a requirement where the reboot of the client machine needs to trigger a disconnect event on the server. We are seeing the disconnect, but it happens after a couple of mins. I'd like it to be immediate. Any ideas how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server emits something known as `heartbeats` to every client.
The client responds directly to the heartbeats, this way the server knows the client is still up.
 (ping / pong)

Reading the `socket.io` doc you got the following options that might interest you for detecting the connection being closed :

```
pingTimeout (Number): how many ms without a pong packet to consider the connection closed (60000)
pingInterval (Number): how many ms before sending a new ping packet (25000)
```

Sources : 
https://github.com/socketio/socket.io#serveroptsobject
https://github.com/socketio/engine.io#methods-1